# How is std::forward_list emplace_after O(1)?

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, forward-list

I'm currently implementing a forward list (Singly linked list).
I noticed that `std::forward_list::emplace_after` is O(1), so the complexity is constant: How is this possible?
I'm asking because:

1. You can have the position of the new element to be in the middle,
2. As far as I know, the only way to find the position where a new element has to be added is to traverse the list with a loop.

Am I missing something?
This is how I currently implement the function.

```
constexpr void emplace_after(iterator position, Args...args) { // Must be O(1)
    size_type index_position = std::distance(begin(), position);

    Node* temp = m_head;
    for (size_type index{ 0 }; index < index_position; ++index) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    Node* next_temp = temp->next;
    Node* current_node = new Node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    temp->next = current_node;
    current_node->next = next_temp;

    temp = nullptr;
    next_temp = nullptr;
    m_size += 1;
}
```

And this is my current forward iterator implementation:

```
template<typename T>
struct forward_iterator {
    Node* m_iterator;

    using value_type = T;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    constexpr forward_iterator(Node* forw_iter = nullptr) : m_iterator{ forw_iter } {}

    constexpr Node* getNodeAddress() const noexcept {
        return m_iterator;
    }

    constexpr Node* getNodeNextAddress() const noexcept {
        return m_iterator->next;
    }

    constexpr reference operator*() const noexcept {
        return m_iterator->data;
    }

    constexpr pointer operator->() const noexcept {
        return m_iterator;
    }

    constexpr forward_iterator& operator++() noexcept {
        m_iterator = m_iterator->next;
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr forward_iterator operator++(int) noexcept {
        forward_iterator tmp(*this);
        this = (this)->next;
        return tmp;
    }

    constexpr friend bool operator== (const forward_iterator& first, const forward_iterator& second) noexcept {
        return (first.m_iterator == second.m_iterator);
    }

    constexpr friend bool operator!=(const forward_iterator& first, const forward_iterator& second) noexcept {
        return !(first.m_iterator == second.m_iterator);
    }
};
```

Comment: But you find the position *before* you call `emplace_after`.  The 'find' operation is not part of `emplace_after`.

Comment: What do you mean? You pass an iterator position as argument to emplace_after.

Comment: `emplace_after` doesn't search anything. It doesn't traverse anything. It simply emplaces a new element at a given position. Do you understand how iterators work and how they are used here?

Comment: *"What do you mean? You pass an iterator position"* Exactly. Finding the right iterator is O(n) (n = the position of the element), but inserting next to it is O(1).

Comment: I am failing to get it. I have implemented the iterators, and if the user calls ```emplace_After(++++++list.begin(), 3)``` the operator++ in my iterator traverses the list already. But then in the actual ```emplace_after``` function I need to find the position and I need a  loop since I need to go to the ```->next``` node until I find the position I want. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SomeoneWithPassion You don't need to find any position. That's what the iterator is for. The iterator points to the list-element after which you want to emplace something.

Comment: I have added my function code on the post now, to show what I mean since I can't seem to understand how this should be done.

Comment: Can you also provide your `iterator` implementation.  From the code shown it would appear that your `iterator` type doesn't convey sufficient information to allow `emplace_after` to have O(1) time complexity.

Comment: I added that now as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding about how iterators are supposed to work in singly linked lists. They are not just an identifier you can (and have to) search for, they should point to an actual node in one way or another.

Illustration:

```
Iterator ------------------+
                           |
                           V 
[Head] -> Node -> Node -> Node -> Node -> Node -> nullptr
```

This means your class `iterator` should contain a `Node *` (Edit: As it already does)

Then your `emplace_back` can look like this:

```
constexpr void emplace_after(iterator position, Args... args)
{   
    Node* temp = position.getNodeAddress(); // retrieve the node position is referring

    Node* next_temp = temp->next;
    Node* current_node = new Node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    temp->next = current_node;
    current_node->next = next_temp;

    temp = nullptr;
    next_temp = nullptr;
    m_size += 1;
}
```

Comment: My class contains a Node iterator. I've updated the thread and added my implementation if you have time to check it. Thank you!

Comment: I see the logic now. This post seems to have fixed my issue. What I was doing wrong was converting the iterator to a Node*, instead of using the function getNodeAddress, which itself returns a Node. Now I see why it didn't work before!

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `std::forward_list<T,Allocator>::emplace_after` is an iterator, which means you need to find the position before emplacing. Therefore, it just need constant time.

Comment: I added my attempt to show what I meant, since I can't seem to understand how to implement this. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

Iterators let you go to the node they refer to in O(1) time.

If your iterator does not, fix it.